# Tomickigrzegorz Script Search Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, json, search, autocomplete

Hi I tried to use the autocomplete script of tomickigrzegorz

https://tomickigrzegorz.github.io/autocomplete/

It work well but I can't understand why the tag  with href external link like https//google.com don't work.

my code for script complex test and example :

```
<div class="info">
              <h4><a  href='https://breakingbadapi.com/' target='_blank'>${el.name}</a></h4>
              <div><b>nickname:</b> - <a class='link-to-api' href="https//google.com" target="_self">${el.nickname}</a></div>
              <div><b>birthday:</b> - ${el.birthday}</div>
              <div><b>status:</b> - ${el.status}</div>
</div>
```

In the search result, I could copy the link but It don't work with just clicking ....

I looked in the scripts, css without seeing why the links are blocked.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thank you. Merci bien.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `preventDefault()` in the [code](https://github.com/tomickigrzegorz/autocomplete/blob/da9ef2e25b19b8a64d0a630e91f2519da5c3327a/sources/js/script.js#L491) which prevents links from working

You can bypass this by using `onclick`

```
<a  href='' onclick="window.open('https://breakingbadapi.com/', '_blank')">${el.name}</a>
```

It looks like this library is created for autocomplete of input fields that's why you can select fields. I would consider using a different library for card searching

Comment: Wonderfull , many thanks, I'll sleeping better next night !
But you wrote " I would consider using a different library for card searching" ... 
I'm interested in other sources for another library to for card searching. Do you have a suggestion?